# Gnome-shell-extension destructor (run on Gnome Shell exit)?

Tags: gjs, gnome-shell-extensions

Is there any trick to run my "destructor" code in an extension when Gnome Shell is closing (e.g. computer turning off)? I need to save some state variables to load them again in `init()` on start.

I need something like function `enable()` or `disable()`. Maybe there is some signal being fired which I could connect my code to?

Comment: Why not use `disable()` in your `extension.js` file?

Comment: I thought `disable()` was **only** run on extension disabling by user from https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. Now I'm not sure, I'll try, thanks.

Comment: It will be run every time your extension get's disabled, which is the case when the shell closes down.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! BTW the lack of gjs documentation makes it a bit painful and I'm feeling stupid while asking such basic questions :-/

Comment: Answered for completion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `disable()`-function inside the `extension.js`-file is called when:

- The user disables an extension in a running shell
- The shell shuts down or restarts

Keep in mind that it's meant to do UI-manipulation, so you should finish it *fast* (no heavy lifting).

Comment: My experience regarding this topic. disable() is **not** called on system shutdown. Just tested it on ubuntu18 with GNOME Shell 3.34.1. Logout and screen lock **is** triggering it.

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome 42; `disable` is not called on shutdown. I wonder if this is a bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: This is a bug; `disable` is not currently being called on shutdown or log out: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2621